# Absolute value => Directly integrable, separable and/or linear?

Tags: calculus

I have previously supplied this question, however it went unanswered:
Is the following directly integrable, separable and/or linear.
EDIT: This is no longer homework as of 10 minutes after this edit.

> $\frac{da}{db} = |a|,a(0) = 0$

$$-------------$$

Direct integration gives: $|a|\cdot b +c$, $\therefore$ $c= 0$, and I believe it is therefore directly integrable. I am not entirely sure however due to the fact that depending on y, it has two derivatives(?)

Also, it takes the form $\frac{da}{db} = f(a)$, whereas I believe the form required for direct integration is $\frac{da}{db} = f(b)$.

$$\frac{1}{|a|}\cdot da = 1\cdot db$$
$$\ln a + c \text{ Note this is undefined(ln0)}$$

I don't believe it is separable, since using initial values, it shouldn't be defined.

However in this case it takes the form $\frac{da}{db} = f(a)f(b)$, where $f(b) = 1$ which seems correct for separation!

Finally, I know it isn't linear as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88669/is-the-absolute-value-function-a-linear-function) proves.

Hints and/or justification are preferred over simply answers! Any help is greatly appreciated!

$$-------------$$

Comment: From: $f(ax+y) = af(x) + f(y).$, it appears it isn't linear as $|ax+y| = |-1| = 1$ $\neq$ $-1\ |1|+|0| = -1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This IVP has no solution as the Cauchy-Peano Theorem states: Where $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y), y(x_0) = y_0$

If $f(x,y)$ is continuous in some rectangle, $R =${$(x,y)| |x-x_0| \lt a, |y - y_0| \lt b$}
then the initial value problem has at least one solution. ($x_0,y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$)

Since it is not continuous, it has no solution.

It is not directly integrable as it has form $\frac{da}{db} = f(a)$. It is required that the IVP take the form $\frac{da}{db} = f(b)$ for it to be directly integrable, however: $\frac{da}{db} = f(a)f(b)$ is a form that is separable.

$$\frac{da}{db} = |a|$$ $$\frac{1}{|a|} \cdot da = 1 \cdot db$$
$$\ln |a| = x + c \text{  This intermediate step has ln|0| which is underfined(given IV)}$$
$$|a| = C\cdot e^x \text{  Where C is a constant e^c}$$

Since it has an intermediate step which is undefined, it cannot be integrated via separation.

Showing that it is not linear can be done via the method outlined in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88669/is-the-absolute-value-function-a-linear-function) similar question: